# Talmud's statement concerning people who believe G-d did not command all 613 mitzvos

Tags: sources-mekorot, talmud-gemara, mitzvah, faith-bitachon-emunah, ikarim

I recall learning in the Talmud (Kesuvos, I think), that if someone believes that G-d gave all of the commandments in the Torah except one, and that one he thinks is nonsense, that shows that the person has substituted his own conclusions for those of the Torah and it therefore shows he does not believe the Torah was given by G-d and, worse, that he may not believe in G-d at all!  I can't recall where I saw this.  Can someone fill me in?

Comment: one related source http://hearos.blogspot.com/2011/12/bechoros-30b-accepting-mitzvos-except.html

Comment: @Danno The statement I recall is more direct than that.  Thanks.

Comment: Understood. Still looking http://www.torah.org/learning/mlife/LORch3-9.html  http://dafyomi.co.il/chulin/points/ch-ps-004.htm

Comment: @Danno Rambam makes the comment, but I don't think he cites the Gemara.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 gemaras that you may be thinking of. Bekhorot 30b says: 
ת"ר הבא לקבל דברי חבירות חוץ מדבר אחד אין מקבלין אותו עובד כוכבים שבא לקבל דברי תורה חוץ מדבר אחד אין מקבלין אותו ר' יוסי בר' יהודה אומר אפי' דקדוק אחד מדברי סופרים. Soncino translates:

> Our Rabbis taught: If one is prepared to accept the obligation of a
>   haber except one religious law, we must not receive him as a haber. If
>   a heathen is prepared to accept the Torah except one religious law, we
>   must not receive him [as an Israelite]. R. Jose son of R. Judah says:
>   Even [if the exception be] one point of the special minutiae of the
>   Scribes’ enactments.

Alternatively, you may be referring to this Gemara (Sanhedrin 99a): תניא אידך כי דבר ה' בזה זה האומר אין תורה מן השמים ואפילו אמר כל התורה כולה מן השמים חוץ מפסוק זה שלא אמרו הקדוש ברוך הוא אלא משה מפי עצמו זהו כי דבר ה' בזה ואפילו אמר כל התורה כולה מן השמים חוץ מדקדוק זה מקל וחומר זה מגזרה שוה זו זה הוא כי דבר ה' בזה.

> Another [Baraitha] taught: Because he hath despised the word of the
>   Lord — this refers to him who maintains that the Torah is not from
>   Heaven. And even if he asserts that the whole Torah is from Heaven,
>   excepting a particular verse, which [he maintains] was not uttered by
>   God but by Moses himself, he is included in 'because he hath despised
>   the word of the Lord.' And even if he admits that the whole Torah is
>   from Heaven, excepting a single point, a particular ad majus deduction
>   or a certain gezerah shawah, — he is still included in 'because he
>   hath despised the word of the Lord'.

Comment: Just what I was looking for, although I prefer the Art Scroll translation.